# Premiere CC: How to select/drag clip in program window?

Tags: premiere, editing, effects

Running Premiere Pro 2018 on Windows. Previously, I could animate the scale and position of the clip in the program window by clicking to select it and using handles to scale, or drag it around within the program monitor. This would create keyframes and update the scale and position settings. It made it very easy to do "pan and scan" type zooms and rolls.  I'm not sure if I was using an earlier version then.

On my current project, I can't select the clip in the Program monitor. I click it with the selection tool and never see handles on the image. Selecting it in the Timeline doesn't do anything either. I *can* add key frames and adjust position numerically in the Effects Monitor panel, but I'd like to use the mouse in some cases. Does anybody know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I found a solution by clicking around finally. In the Effects Control panel, clicking the Motion property label causes handles to appear on the video in the Program Monitor. Then, with the Selection tool, you can drag the image to reposition it, or drag a corner handle to scale it. I believe I was able to do this in earlier versions without first selecting the Motion label, but at least I can do what I want easily now.